# How to display custom cards in Google Now

Tags: android, schema, google-now

How to display cards in Google Now by sending email to the corresponding gmail account. Just like the one mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/google-now)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below StackOverflow question it may help you to research on this topic:

[Create custom google now cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220923/create-custom-google-now-cards)

For creating card google is reading details from your personal gmail account, like if you have your flight ticket in your mail, then google will show your schedule flight details in Event section.

They are creating card using your mail related to that even in your inbox.